# SSRS Category group displays category group label vertically

Tags: ssrs-2008

Is there a way to display the category group label horizontally in SSRS stacked bar chart?

The first group label displays horizontally i.e. (2011, 2012), but the second label displays the label vertically i.e. (US) in SSRS 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and circumvented it by using a table with row groups and a "Data Bar" from the toolbox.

How to set it up:
Add some groups to a table in the leftmost columns, same as the categories in the bar chart, and then a data bar in the rightmost column, then turn some borders on or off for formatting.

You can add a value axis, but it will show up on every row. Make it only visible in the top or bottom row with the following expression on Visible:

`=Iif(Fields!ChildCategoryGroup.Value = Last(Fields!ChildCategoryGroup.Value, "Tablix1") And Fields!ParentCategoryGroup.Value = Last(Fields!ParentCategoryGroup.Value, "Tablix1"), "True", "False")`

OR:

If you don't mind your parent group label showing up on every row, change your bar chart like this:

- Merge the parent and child groups: move the parent groupings and Sorting to the child group or vice versa
- Change the Label of the child group to something like this `=Fields!ParentCategoryGroup.Value & " - " & Fields!ChildCategoryGroup.Value`

Note: the labels will look cleaner if you align them left.

(P.S. I know this is an old topic, but I found no answers to this anywhere so there you go.)